# Limited screen recording time in VLC media player

Tags: vlc-media-player

I'm using the screen recording feature in VLC, but every time it gets to about 13 minutes, or 56 MB, it just stops recording: I've been letting the video I want saved run in the player whilst recording is on - but twice its cut out at 13 minutes.

Is there a limit to record time / file size I'm missing in the settings somewhere?

Update: so I realised the issue was actually that the stream which I was saving seemed to skip at that point for some reason. VLC was then stopping the recording happening.

Is it possible to stop VLC automatically ending the recording at this small skips? The stream itself just keeps going after the jump - and I just want the whole thing saved to one file.

Comment: Are you recording a video that is playing or your desktop?

Comment: Hi @Moab - thanks for the reply. I've got a stream from the internet I want to save and then tidy up the audio of. I've realised the issue is not time limits, but that the stream has little skips, possibly where the internet on the original stream dropped out. I've updated the question with the details - do you know of anyway to stop VLC automatically ending the recording as I describe above?

Comment: Most likely out of space on the drive, or the drive turned off (external drive). This is not a limitation of VLC.

Comment: Definitely not out of space and it's an internal drive; screen is on etc so hasn't gone to sleep.